# How to change job parameter of a map-reduce job on run-time?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I have written a map job which takes up a bunch of tweets and list of keyword, and emits tweets counts for keywords

```
@Override
public void map(Object key, Text value, Context output) throws IOException,
        InterruptedException {

    JSONObject tweetObject = null;

    ArrayList<String> keywords = this.getKeyWords();

    try {
        tweetObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(value.toString());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (tweetObject != null) {
        String tweetText = (String) tweetObject.get("text");

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(tweetText);

        ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            tokens.add(st.nextToken());
        }

        for (String keyword : keywords) {

            for (String token : tokens) {
                token = token.toLowerCase();
                if (token.equals(keyword) || token.contains(keyword)) {
                    output.write(new Text(keyword), one);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    output.write(new Text("count"), one);

}

ArrayList<String> getKeyWords() {

    ArrayList<String> keywords = new ArrayList<String>();

    keywords.add("vodka");
    keywords.add("tequila");
    keywords.add("mojito");
    keywords.add("margarita");

    return keywords;

}
```

Right now my keywords list is static/hard-coded in the map-reduce jar file, how can I make this dynamic? i.e. I want to be able to change the keywords on run-time?

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways from the top off my head: query a webservice, read a file.

In any case you probably don't want to execute this for every record you map. It is fairly common to use a caching layer (e.g. Guava) to cache an external data source and invalidate it for example by time or modification.

Comment: How will do it by reading a file? The map job will run on various servers, the path might be different for different servers.

Comment: @Dude you have HDFS at your disposal, why reading from local disk?

Comment: But if I put keyword file in hdfs, it will be split across multiple machines? How will I access that file in map/reduce job?can you show me an example?